# Ruby lambda not available to all methods in class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just wrote my first lambda in Ruby and have run into an issue when using it with Rails.

I have a class called Material:

```
class Material < ApplicationRecord

  to_kilobytes = lambda { |bytes| bytes / 1000 }
  to_megabytes = lambda { |bytes| bytes / 1000000 }

  def size
    size = self.attachment_file_size

    if size < 999999
      to_kilobytes.call(size)
    elsif size >= 1000000
      to_megabytes.call(size)
    end
  end
end
```

I am trying to call this `size` method on my `material` object in order to find size conversion rates for files. The `attachment_file_size` method is provided by the Rubygem [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip).

When I try calling the size method on this material object in my `show.html.erb` file -

```
<span><%= @material.size %></span>
```

I am getting the following error.

> undefined local variable or method `to_kilobytes' for Material:0x007fc6f6cba2e0

If I move the lambdas inside the `size` method it works fine. I realize this is a scoping error, I am just confused why these who lambdas are not able to be called on the size method since they are global in the class. Can somebody explain?

Comment: i don't think local variables outside of a method are ever accessible from the method.

Comment: What makes you think they are global? Hint: how does Ruby distinguish between different variable types? What does it mean when a variable starts with a lowercase letter? What does a global variable start with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`to_kilobytes` and `to_megabytes` local variables are in the scope of `class...end`, but not inside the method `size`. Because each `def..end` creates a new scope in Ruby. Either make them instance methods, or create as constants and then u can use it without any scope issues. Like:

```
class Material < ApplicationRecord

  TO_KILOBYTES = lambda { |bytes| bytes / 1000 }
  TO_MEGABYTES = lambda { |bytes| bytes / 1000000 }

  def size
    size = self.attachment_file_size

    if size < 999999
      TO_KILOBYTES.call(size)
    elsif size >= 1000000
      TO_MEGABYTES.call(size)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

`to_kilobytes` and `to_megabytes` are class local variables, so they cannot be accessed in instance methods (`size`).

---

In Rails, we have a method called [`number_to_human_size`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_human_size), I think It will help you:

> Formats the bytes in number into a more understandable representation
>   (e.g., giving it 1500 yields 1.5 KB). This method is useful for
>   reporting file sizes to users. You can customize the format in the
>   options hash.
>
> See number_to_human if you want to pretty-print a generic number.

**Examples**

```
number_to_human_size(123)                                          # => 123 Bytes
number_to_human_size(1234)                                         # => 1.21 KB
number_to_human_size(12345)                                        # => 12.1 KB
number_to_human_size(1234567)                                      # => 1.18 MB
number_to_human_size(1234567890)                                   # => 1.15 GB
number_to_human_size(1234567890123)                                # => 1.12 TB
number_to_human_size(1234567890123456)                             # => 1.1 PB
number_to_human_size(1234567890123456789)                          # => 1.07 EB
number_to_human_size(1234567, precision: 2)                        # => 1.2 MB
number_to_human_size(483989, precision: 2)                         # => 470 KB
number_to_human_size(1234567, precision: 2, separator: ',')        # => 1,2 MB
number_to_human_size(1234567890123, precision: 5)                  # => "1.1228 TB"
number_to_human_size(524288000, precision: 5)                      # => "500 MB"
```